# How to create Font size options (Small, Normal, Large ) for the entire app?

Tags: android, textview, font-size

I want to have a setting activity where the user be able to change the font size of the text for the entire app ... I also only have one textview which makes the work easy but I can't figure it out by myself.

for example I have an activity where it displays the texts and it's called (Contentactivity)

and then there will be another activity named (Settingactivity ) where from here the user be able to change the font size of the text of the  Contentactivity .

I hope it's clear and thank you very much for your help .

Comment: Set text size in xml as "sp" not "dp". and after that change text size from setting

Comment: Thank you my friend @Phil3992 that's what I am looking for and I'm gonna try it out :)

Comment: @ashish I  always use sp format but I want to set a font size options programmatically . Thank you :)

Comment: You can change system font using below code

`Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 1.0);`
and after this give permission in menifest file

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it :

1. Create a style for each wanted text size :

   `<style name="RegularSizedText">
           <item name="text_size">20sp</item>
   </style>
   <style name="LargeSizedText">
           <item name="text_size">35sp</item>
   </style>`
2. Create an enumeration/map of text sizes, associating each style ID with a number (`R.style.RegularSizedText` <=> 0, `R.style.LargeSizedText` <=> 1...) - you must not change it afterwards or it will break the settings when updating the app, you can only append parameters but never remove/insert any
3. In your shared properties (or any other parameters storage system), put the number ID of the style of the current font size - add it to your settings activity
4. In each Activity of your app, put this piece of code in the `onCreate` method : 
   `getTheme().applyStyle(myStyle, false);`
   Where myStyle is the style ID corresponding to the stored parameter (so if the user selected the font parameter #0 it will be `R.style.RegularSizedText`)

You must never store the style ID directly as it will be broken when updating the app (the Android R IDs are not the same from a build to another).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sp` instead of `dp` when setting your size. This will guarantee that your text always adjust to the screen size and user's preference in **Settings**.

Check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/1889768) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can change system font using below code

`Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 1.0);`

and after this give permission in menifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

Comment: This can be given only to System based apps.